# JAXB Unmarshalling Interception for POJO Creation

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am using JAXB marshalling and unmarshalling to transfer data between server and client.  As the data classes are shared by both Server and client this seems like the right way to do things.  The examples I've found on the web are fine for the data that is transitory, data which will be thrown away when a new request is made of the server.

But some of my data isn't transitory, the subsequent polls of the server are looking for updates.  I've include a timestamp in the response so these kind of request only need to report those items that have been modified.

What I am looking for is a way of intercepting the unmarshalling process so that, at point of POJO creation my code is called to do its thing.  Rather than just create a new instance blindly, I want to use the unique identifier, which is encoded into the attributes of the XML element node, to lookup the the already fetched, but out of date, instance I have in the cache and return that.  Therefore, when unmarshalling continues it becomes a true update.

My POJO data objects, by the way, support both veto and property change support, and the GUI code uses property change events to update refresh itself, and may well use the veto to note if the user is modifing something that has been updated elsewhere.  An example is listed below:

```
@Entity(name="Operative")
@Table(name="vOperatives")
@XmlRootElement(name="operative")
public class OperativeEntity 
    extends AbstractEntity {

    public static final String IDENT_PROPERTY = "identity";
    public static final String GIVEN_NAME_PROPERTY = "given-name";
    public static final String FAMILY_NAME_PROPERTY = "family-name";
    public static final String EMAIL_PROPERTY = "email";
    public static final String EMAIL_VERIFIED_PROPERTY = "email-verified";

    private volatile UUID uuid;
    private volatile String givenName;
    private volatile String familyName;
    private volatile String email;
    private volatile boolean emailVerified;

    public OperativeEntity() {
    }

    public OperativeEntity(UUIDFactory factory) {
        setUUID(factory.generate());
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="uuid", length=40)
    @XmlAttribute(name="uuid")
    public String getIdent() {
        return null == uuid ? null : uuid.toString();
    }

    public void setIdent(String uuid) {
        setUUID(UUID.fromString(uuid));
    }

    @Transient
    @XmlTransient
    public UUID getUUID() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUUID(UUID id) {
        if (null == id)
            throw new NullPointerException("No UUID given");
        uuid = id;
    }

    @Column(name="gvn", length=60, nullable=true)
    @XmlAttribute(name="given-name")
    public String getGivenName() {
        return givenName;
    }

    public void setGivenName(String newName)
        throws PropertyVetoException {

        if (null == givenName && null == newName)
            return;

        else if (null != givenName && givenName.equals(newName))
            return;

        final String oldName = givenName;
        fireVetoableChange(GIVEN_NAME_PROPERTY, oldName, newName);
        givenName = newName;
        firePropertyChange(GIVEN_NAME_PROPERTY, oldName, newName);
    }

    @Column(name="fmly", length=60, nullable=true)
    @XmlAttribute(name="family-name")
    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String newName)
        throws PropertyVetoException {

        if (null == familyName && null == newName)
            return;

        else if (null != familyName && familyName.equals(newName))
            return;

        final String oldName = familyName;
        fireVetoableChange(FAMILY_NAME_PROPERTY, oldName, newName);
        familyName = newName;
        firePropertyChange(FAMILY_NAME_PROPERTY, oldName, newName);
    }

    @Column(name="eMail", nullable=true)
    @XmlAttribute(name="e-mail")
    public String getEMail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEMail(String newEMail)
        throws PropertyVetoException {

        if (null == email && null == newEMail)
            return;

        else if (null != email && email.equals(newEMail))
            return;

        final String oldEMail = email;
        fireVetoableChange(EMAIL_PROPERTY, oldEMail, newEMail);
        email = newEMail;
        firePropertyChange(EMAIL_PROPERTY, oldEMail, newEMail);
    }

    @Column(name="vrfd", nullable=true)
    @XmlAttribute(name="email-verified")
    public boolean isEMailVerified() {
        return emailVerified;
    }

    public void setEMailVerified(boolean newVerified)
        throws PropertyVetoException {

        if (newVerified == emailVerified)
            return;

        final boolean oldVerified = emailVerified;
        fireVetoableChange(EMAIL_VERIFIED_PROPERTY, oldVerified, newVerified);
        emailVerified = newVerified;
        firePropertyChange(EMAIL_VERIFIED_PROPERTY, oldVerified, newVerified);
    }
}
```